# Use POSTed JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

So I'm trying to create a handler to respond to the JSON sent by Plex's webhook feature using PHP and I'm failing to see where I'm going wrong.

Annoyingly it seems to work fine when I write a quick curl request myself, but when the request is sent from Plex it just doesn't work. Using file_put_contents I can see that $_POST is receiving the JSON as expected, however every variable is empty beyond that. Outputting json_last_error to a file gives me 0.

Any help here would be great. I'm not exactly an expert and just cannot see why this isn't working. I did also try not using json_decode on $_POST and instead treated it as a string, using strpos to find specific events, players, and types, however that also returned false on all occasions.

```
$jsonText = $_POST;
$myArray = json_decode($jsonText, true);

$type = $myArray["Metadata"]["type"];
$player = $myArray["Player"]["title"];
$event = $myArray["event"];

if($type == "movie" && $player == "TV UE40K5500") {
    switch($event) {
        case "media.play":
        case "media.resume":
            ifttt("tv_play");
            break;
        case "media.pause":
        case "media.stop":
            ifttt("tv_stop");
            break;       
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to `var_dump($_POST);`. Then most likely you'll be able to do `$jsonText = $_POST['foo'];` where `$_POST['foo'];` is the `POST` param that contains your `JSON`.

Comment: what is the content of `$_POST`, did you make a typo with the key names, is the json having a specific key,

Comment: You code has no error handling whatsoever. If it supposed to give a response to an external request it should also give a response when an error occurs, any error. So use a `default` case, and give feedback on the absence of expected values.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying that you can see $_POST results (using file_put_contents) from both your curl and your plex requests, but PHP isn't able to work with the data from Plex? I've never worked with plex, so no ideas for that, but if both your curl request and the request from plex send POST data (as your file_put_contents() demonstrates), I would suggest you output the $_POST values from the curl and plex requests, and do a diff on them. Perhaps plex is generating JSON with a non-standard escape character or something?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the suggestions. I added in several log file writes to work out where I was losing the information. I was finally able to deduce that I needed to access `$_POST["payload"]` for the JSON sent from Plex.

I have definitely learned to have a degree of logging from now on, as it makes error checking a thousand times easier.